# How to filter a large object from an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I cannot seem to grasp how to use an array of values to filter an object. I am unfamiliar with terms/syntax to get this working. I thought I would need .filter => function but no success.
Hopefully the following dummy code can allow someone to see what I am trying to do - thanks

```
// Javascript array object
var str = "Organization A,Organization B,Organization X,Organization R,Organization P"
var arr = new Array(); 
arr = str.split(","); 

// object     
json=[
{"organization":"Organization A","host":"Computer 001"},
{"organization":"Organization B","host":"Computer 002"},
{"organization":"Organization C","host":"Computer 003"},
{"organization":"Organization A","host":"Computer 004"},
{"organization":"Organization D","host":"Computer 005"}
]

// result needed is to return the structure above that has organization(s) in arr 
// below is simple example for 1 successful test but need to get filter all in arr
// .map? .find? 
res = json.filter(f => f.organization==="Organization A")
```

Comment: could you share how you resulted json should be? like an example ```json```

Comment: That's not JSON. That's a JavaScript array literal.

Comment: json.filter(f => arr.includes(f.organization))

Comment: You don't want to filter an object. You want to filter an array of objects.

Comment: @jabaa - as mentioned I am unfamiliar with the terms and syntax but apparently I am definitely not alone as the very acronym JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is enough to confuse. Even with my literal format... there are many sites state it as a JSON example that contains an array of objects and I imagine is why VeKri answer worked. I will definitely have to research this more and appreciate your insight on the matter - thanks!

Comment: @Vekri: json.filter(f => arr.includes(f.organization)) was the correct answer

Comment: You should avoid sites that use this term for JavaScript literals. All sites I know are horrible, e.g. geeksforgeeks or w3schools. They contain wrong information, bad practice and outdated code.